# Why is my asp mvc ajax GET request with multiple parameters is not working?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Sorry to post. I saw SO MANY answers here and also [this great post](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/795483/Do-GET-POST-PUT-DELETE-in-asp-net-MVC-with-Jquery) but my call is still not working. Below is my config :

**Route config**

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "MyRoute",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}/{age}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "MyAction"
                               , id = UrlParameter.Optional
                               , name = UrlParameter.Optional
                               , age = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );
```

**Action method in home controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyAction(int id, string name, int age)
{ 
    // Do some work and return View()
}
```

**My Javascript Code**

```
function MyFunction(id)
{
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var age = document.getElementById('age').value;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            "id": id,
            "name": name,
            "age": age
        },
        // url: '@Url.Action("MyAction", "Home")',
        url: '/Home/MyAction',
        success: function (response) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

This code miserably fails... It ALWAYS goes to `error` and the alert box shows for error all the time. It never goes to the `MyAction` action of `Home` controller whatever format I user for `url`.

What's going on ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

when you create a get request, you dont have any data request, you can use only query string, not Body data

```
function MyFunction(id)
{
   var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
   var age = document.getElementById('age').value;

   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      //data: {
      //    "id": id,
      //    "name": name,
      //    "age": age
      //},
      // url: '@Url.Action("MyAction", "Home")',
      url: '/Home/MyAction/'+id+'/'+name+'/'+age,
      success: function (response) {
        alert("success");
      },
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert("error");
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: awesome Kisame. It worked.... BUT it still calls the error function. I don't know why. The action was performed successfully though and my database was properly updated...BUT `return View(model)` failed....I guess that's  something else. Thank you .

Comment: @Bloomberg58 , what is the code in your actin mehtod?
i think you must use "return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);"

Comment: I guess I should have do that. I was doing `return Json("mystring")` or `return null`. After looking around I have chosen to return a simple `string` and to not specify a `dataType` in `$.ajax`. This sovled my problem.